# How to implement WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting in UWP VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts, uwp, data-visualization

There a bunch of examples online regarding this package. But all are in C# and I can't seem to reproduce those examples in VB.NET. Could anyone post a simple code on, for example, how to use the LineSeries.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the site I use for converting c# code: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @FloatingKiwi Thanks for providing a long-term solution to my problem. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But all are in C# and I can't seem to reproduce those examples in VB.NET. Could anyone post a simple code on, for example, how to use the `LineSeries`

I created a VB.Net sample based on the C# sample in this [blog](https://eren.ws/2013/10/15/using-graphs-and-charts-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-11/)

The xaml code is the same as C# one, add `LineSeries` and set binding to `IndependentValuePath` & `DependentValuePath`:

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="LineChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="400" Height="400">
            <Charting:LineSeries Title="Smartphone Companies" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        </Charting:Chart>
```

Create data list and assign to `LineSeries`:

```
Dim rand As New Random()
        Dim financialStuffList As New List(Of FinancialStuff)()
        financialStuffList.Add(New FinancialStuff() With {
                               .Name = "MSFT",
                               .Amount = rand.[Next](0, 200)
                               })
        financialStuffList.Add(New FinancialStuff() With {
                               .Name = "AAPL",
                               .Amount = rand.[Next](0, 200)
                               })
        financialStuffList.Add(New FinancialStuff() With {
                               .Name = "GOOG",
                               .Amount = rand.[Next](0, 200)
                               })
        financialStuffList.Add(New FinancialStuff() With {
                               .Name = "BBRY",
                               .Amount = rand.[Next](0, 200)
                               })
TryCast(LineChart.Series(0), LineSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList
```

**Check my completed sample [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkitChartingVBApp1)**